# any layout manager for ConstraintLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout

I know ConstraintLayout is provided from android studio 2.2.

But, any ConstraintLayoutManager is provided too ?

(something like LinearLayoutManager)

so that we can use it in RecyclerView and so on..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No. still not. Just use LinearLayoutManager if you only want to use RecyclerView.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a ConstraintLayout to a LinearLayout like this.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/recycleritem_id"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="100dp"
android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
android:gravity="start"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:clickable="true"
android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground">


<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="22dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```